# add array to another array of arrays TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to simulate this object to send it with post request:

```
export interface ISample{
    data:  string;
    gas :IGas[];
}
export interface IGas {
    id :string;
    type:string;
}
```

At the component, I created addSample().

```
addPrelevementACR() {
  let sample= {} as ISample;
  let gasCO2= {} as IGas;
  let gasCO= {} as IGas;
  sample.data= this.data;
  gasCO2.id="1";
  gasCO2.type=""CO2";
  sample.gas[0]=gasCO2;
  gasCO.id="2";
  gasCO.type="CO"
  sample.gas[1]=gasCO;
}
```

I got this error: Cannot set property '1' of undefined

How can i resolve this problem

Comment: you need to initialize the array so before `samples.gas[0]` put `sample.gas = [];`

Comment: Not sure that typescript is wrong here. In your snippet, you never set a `gas` property on the `sample` object, so it would legitimately be undefined. Maybe you left out a line like `sample.gas = []` or `let sample = { gas: [] } as ISample`?

Comment: yeah I left sample.gas = [] ; I do not know this before.